# Google Drive PDF - How to Go To Specific Page in PDF Opened In Chrome

Tags: google-drive, google-chrome, pdf

## Expected

Quickly go to specific page in a PDF opened in Google Drive with a Chrome based browser.

**i.e.**

In Mac's *Preview* app on desktop, *Go* > *Go to Page...* allows the user to go to a specific page.

[image]

## Observed

There is no feature to to go to a specific page in a PDF opened in Google Drive.

[image]

## Attempted Solution

Appending the shared document url with an `&page=11` or `&pageNumber=11` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround by opening the locally Google Drive synced *PDF* directly in a Chrome based browser.

1. Sync Google Drive files with local machine.
2. Secondary click the local file > Select *Open With* > Choose *Chrome* or a Chrome based browser to open the file.
3. Go to a specific page number by selecting the page number at the top of the document and typing in a new page number.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+p on keyboard. Then it will open that PDF in a separate tab where you can jump to a page.

[image: Seperate tab opened when pressed ctrl+p]